# Preg_match() from string issue

Tags: php, regex, usort

### Situation

I am trying to capture an element of a string with a regex. I am trying to retrieve the offset from these strings:

```
America/Iqaluit (-4:00)
America/Anchorage (-8:00)
```

These string are passed in a function that is used by the [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function as so `usort($timezones, "sortByTime");`. Here is the code I am using to sort my elements:

```
function sortByTime($a, $b) {
    if(preg_match("/^[A-z]*\/[A-z]* \((-[0-9]:[0-9]{2})\)/", $a, $matches)){
        $tz[0] = $matches[1];
    }

    if(preg_match("/^[A-z]*\/[A-z]* \((-[0-9]:[0-9]{2})\)/", $b, $matches)){
        $tz[1] = $matches[1];
    }

    return $tz[1] - $tz[0];
}
```

### Problem

The preg_match function is not working with the variables `$a` and `$b`. I tried changing the variable with an inline string and it worked. Here is an example:

```
preg_match("/^[A-z]*\/[A-z]* \((-[0-9]:[0-9]{2})\)/", $b, $matches); //Doesn't work
preg_match("/^[A-z]*\/[A-z]* \((-[0-9]:[0-9]{2})\)/", "America/Yellowknife (-6:00)", $matches); //Works
```

Why and how can I fix this issue?

Thank you.

### Edit

Please note that the $timezones array has a structure like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["America/Adak"]=>
  string(21) "America/Adak  (-9:00)"
  ["America/Anchorage"]=>
  string(26) "America/Anchorage  (-8:00)"
}
```

Comment: Can you verify that `$timezones` is an array of timezones? Similarly, are `$a` and `$b` timezone strings?

Comment: Yes they are. I will update the post

Comment: Maybe there are timezones that don't match `[A-z]*\/[A-z]*`? Or timezones with double digit offsets, such as: `Foo/Bar (-20:00)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have 2 spaces in your timezones, so:

```
/^[A-z]*\/[A-z]*  \((-[0-9]:[0-9]{2})\)/
// or
/^[A-z]*\/[A-z]*\s*\((-[0-9]:[0-9]{2})\)/
```

If you're just interested in the time a partial match might be better:

```
/\(([-+][0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})\)$/
```

Comment: That was not exactly it, but you leaded me to a working solution! Here is the regex I came up with: /[-+][0-9][0-9]?:[-+]?[0-9]{2}/

Comment: So `+4:-15` is also valid?

Comment: I saw that the generated array was adding some strange values like +4:-15... It is a bit weird but I will keep it that way!

Answer (score 0):

Try it: `/^\w+\/\w+ \((-?\d:[\d]{2})\)/`

Comment: Could you explain this solution a bit more?

Comment: The answer that Doge provided is working. Thank you for the help!